# Does this simple inequality have a name?

Tags: reference-request, inequalities, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}$ be nonnegative numbers such that $m \leq x_{i} \leq M$. Let 
$$
S=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_{i}}
$$
and
$$
Q=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_{i}^{2}}.
$$

Then 
$$
Q \leq S(M+m)-nMm.
$$

This has been recently discovered by at least two different people (including myself) but I am sure that it has come up many times before. Does it have a standard name or reference?

Comment: I guess this is equivalent to the inequality $x^2 \leq x(m+M) - Mm,$ since it must be true term by term ($n=1$ case seems to imply the claim in general). So that inequality might have a name if such a thing exists. The fact that $M \geq x$ then immediately implies the claim, so it might not, because it could be seen as being too easy, since it doesn't seem like there's any trick.

Comment: @J.E.Pascoe That's a nice proof - thanks! Still looking for the provenance, though...

Comment: If $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, this inequality describes a relationship between ${\rm tr}\ A$ and ${\rm tr}\ A^2$.

Comment: @DavidHandelman Can you please elaborate a bit? 10x!

Comment: If $A$ has eigenvalues (counting multiple ones, including what are sometimes called algebraic ones, really bad terminology) $(x_i)$, then ${\rm tr}\ A = \sum x_i$ and ${\rm tr}\ A^2 = \sum x_i^2$.

Answer (score 5):

As @J.E.Pascoe notes the question reduces to the case $n=1$. The fact that $m\leq x$ and $x\leq M$ imply that $x^2+Mm \leq mx + xM$ is a special case of the [rearrangement inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality).

Comment: Irinically, my original overwrought proof used the Gruss inequality - which is a complement to Chebyshev. So it all comes together. :)

Answer (score 2):

I first came across this inequality (n=1 case) from the short note  http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1965-016-05/S0002-9939-1965-0180561-X/S0002-9939-1965-0180561-X.pdf

which says that if $m\le A\le M$, then $(M-A)(A-m)$ is again positive semidefinite. This inequality has intimate connection with the Kantrovich inequality.